# Organization Hierarchy using Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am looking to work on Organization Chart and related pieces. In order to build the same, I am looking to leverage the [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview) for data retrieval.

**Question 1**

I don't see a direct endpoint that allows me to pull the entire hierarchy (upwards). So, is the only option available would require to write a recursive code to pull upwards hierarchy starting at a particular user i.e. get manager of current user, then get manager of manager and so on until you are done with hierarchy.

**Question 2**

Also, there are other options like Azure AD API. However, there is a general recommendation from MS on leveraging the MS Graph endpoint instead of specific product focused endpoints. Requesting for thoughts on the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q1:  Nope - we don't have this today. Please file a request for this on [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis) and others can also vote for this feature.

Q2:  Whatever is exposed by Azure AD is already exposed in Microsoft Graph with a few exceptions. As such, the recursive manager *function* doesn't exist there either. We'd like developers to use Microsoft Graph where possible.  The future is Microsoft Graph, and if we built such a feature, that would be where we would expose it.

Hope this helps,

Comment: In order to close out, we are leveraging MS Graph for retrieval of user information and for full experience, driving them to the Delve page of the user.

Comment: In Teams, when you open a contact, there is an Organization tab that shows a full hierarchy of the particular employee. How has this been built? Is source code available? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-organization-tab-in-teams-ff02568b-290a-46d6-ae7a-cda22f723894

Comment: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$expand=manager($levels=max;$select=id,displayName)&$select=id,displayName&$count=true   With request header ConsistencyLevel: eventual  . This end point is giving the whole hierarchy upwards.

Comment: Does the SDK support the recursive fetch of managers upwards in the hierarchy?

Comment: @VenkateshKalikiri - yes, check Example #2 (C#) on the [doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-manager?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

Answer (score 5):

Up-

```
GET /me/manager
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/manager
```

Down-

```
GET /me/directReports
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/directReports
```

Documentation-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-manager?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-directreports?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Test it out [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/preview).