# How to automate information extraction about an organization's hierarchy from outlook mail?

Tags: outlook, data-mining

I want to get information about a company's hierarchy, i.e who reports to whom. In microsoft outlook there is an organization tab where I can see it. Is there a process to do this directly and get the output as a CSV?

Comment: You may consider using Graph API, see [Organization Hierarchy using Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44145997/organization-hierarchy-using-microsoft-graph) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In the Outlook Object Model, you can use `ExchangeUser.GetExchangeUserManager()` and `ExchangeUser.GetDirectReports()`. From there you can build the complete org hierarchy.

The initial [ExchangeUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser) object can come the current user (`Namespace.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser()`), message sender (`MailItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser()`) or an arbitrary user resolved by name (`Application.Session.CreateRecipient` / `Recipient.Resolve` / `Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser()`).